Permissions.RequestAsync() not working in .net maui Android 14
I'm developping a .net maui application and I'm facing a problem when requesting permissions in Android 14.
For some reason when I use "Permissions.RequestAsync()" the dialog box doesn't appear in Android 14, I used Android 12 emulators and an android 11 physical device and both worked as espected.
The weird thing is that the permissions doesn't even show in the Settings of the device.
Here is my code:
 public static async Task<bool> HasStoragePermission()
 {
     PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
     PermissionStatus status2 = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

     return status == PermissionStatus.Granted && status2 == PermissionStatus.Granted;
 }

 public static async Task<bool> RequestPermissionStorage()
 {            
     var status2 = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
     var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();            
     return HasStoragePermission().Result;
 }

And here is my android manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">    
  </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>


Do not use Result

Also  read this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

From the target android 13, the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> has been removed, so the dialog about permission request will never appear on the android 13 or higher. The value of the Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead> will always be PermissionStatus.Denied.  This is also the case with Permissions.StorageRead.
But as a workaround, you can change your application's target android version to the android 12 to make the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission request alert will still appear on the device with android 13 or higher.
So you can try to add the following code in the AndroidManifest.xml:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- add the code below -->
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

Note:
And there is a relative issue, you can follow it up here:
Permissions CheckStatusAsync Or CheckStatusAsync returns Denied instead of restricted

As another workaround to solve this issue on Android 13 or higher, you can use Android Debug Bridge (adb) to manually grant READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. I'm not sure whether this is a good way for solving problems like this but it seems to do what is needed.

Firstly, install Android Debug bridge and add it to your system
PATH

Secondly, open command window (cmd) and type:
adb devices

hit enter and you should be able to see your connected Android
device

Next step is to manually grant permissions to your app (package).
List all installed packages and find yours:
adb shell pm list packages

Grant permissions:
adb shell pm grant com.yourpackage.abcd android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE    

adb shell pm grant com.yourpackage.abcd android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE



